# RegEx for setting IMG src = ""

Tags: regex

I have raw HTML and I need to set all IMG src="http://foo".

This is the RegEx I have so far, and it seems to work.  In my environment, it is safe to assume that tags are uppercase and attributes are lowercase.  I am doing this in .Net, but I don't think that the platform really matters here.  \s is any whitespace in the .Net RegEx engine.

Can anybody improve on it?

```
Regex.Replace(htmlText, "(<IMG[^>]*\\ssrc=\")([^\"]*)(\"[^>]*>)", "$1http://foo$3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not a regexpert by any means, but try txt2re.com

maybe this will get you started: http://txt2re.com/index-ruby.php3?s=%3CIMG%20src=%22http://foo.bar/baz.jpg%22%20/%3E&1

Comment: This is a great tip for learning and using regular expressions. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Thanks! It's nice to see a 2 year-old comment still be useful.

Comment: Page is no longer there.

Answer (score 2):

Match the entire IMG tag first, and then match the `src="([^\"]*)"` attribute, replacing it, giving you a replacement string for the src="..." part only.

You can then use the original match, and search for the whole tag, and replace it with this whole tag.

Comment: So the search for image tag would be "<[Ii][Mm][Gg][^>]*>", and you could catch the src tag as lowercase, or insensitive in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe allow for multiple spaces with `\s+`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use an HTML parser. IMO, you're much better off using a parser than regex for this task.

Comment: +1.  Although I would normally agree with this completely, sometimes, an HTML parser doesn't work.  In the case of my question (an old one), using an HTML parsing engine was taking way too long because I had a lot of HTML to work over in a short period of time.  The regex approach was significantly faster, yet less robust.  This was not indicated in the OP, however.

Comment: The hipster hacker voice in my head says to use concurrency/MapReduce in that case. Or just grok with grep like a normal, sane person!